# I need a word to describe a group which is not accepting of others not of themselves. Sample sentence below

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english

Your organization treats people in a very "exclusionary" manner. ( Meaning that it is a group that is not accepting of others not of themselves.

Comment: What's wrong with "exclusionary?"  It's in the dictionary.  http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/exclusionary?s=t

Comment: When I read your title I immediately thought "exclusionary".  It's the term commonly used for this.

Comment: If not exclusionary (new word to me) then *exclusive*?

Answer (score 2):

There is ['cliquey'](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cliquey?s=t):

> Cliquey, the **adjectival form** of Clique:
>
> 1 - a small, exclusive group of people; coterie; set.
>
> www.dictionary.com

Comment: +1 Also [cliquish](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/clique?q=cliquish#clique__5)

Answer (score 1):

A group that closes themself off from outside influences will often be called "insular"

> **insular**
>
> characteristic of an isolated people; especially :  being, having, or reflecting a narrow provincial viewpoint

Though this might sound ill fitting, their examples show how it fits your needs:

> Examples of insular
>
> the insular world of boarding schools
> an insular community that is not receptive of new ideas, especially from
> outsiders

[Source: Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/insular)

Answer (score 0):

The best choice is [discriminatory](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/discriminatory):  Marked by or showing prejudice, bias.

> Your organization treats people in a very discriminatory manner.

Comment: Down-voter please explain?

Comment: +1. I'd accept this answer if I were the OP. Common service agreements would state that "discrimination" of any kind: including but not limited to religion, sex, race, ethnicity, gender, sexual orientation, culture, caste or creed is strictly prohibited.